# i want to use Powershell to subtract a numeric value (in a .csv file) in lets say ' B2' from an adjacent cell lets say 'C2'

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, range, subtraction

i want to use Powershell to subtract a numeric value (in a .csv file) in lets say ' E2' from an adjacent cell lets say 'D2' but only if the text in 'A2' starts with a letter C. the sum result should be displayed in 'F2', if 'A2' does not start with the letter C it copies cell 'D2' to 'F2'

this should happen for all following rows

```
Serial         Date        Mono    Colour  Spotcol  result
CNFL64383      07/07/2022  3994    19990   2167     17823
74648160200FK  07/07/2022  771941  0       0        0
VNF4J20449     07/07/2022                           0
CNJL40076      07/07/2022  6369    3602    762      2840
CNJK65021      07/07/2022  19431   10444   839      9605
CNB3Q1NBJG     07/07/2022  199     171     0        171
75280520H5VMT  07/07/2022  6532    12715   622      12715
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

any help would be greatly appreciated as this has been frying my brain for some time now :)

Comment: Please provide what code you've written for this and where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried to do it on your own, you should post your code so we can help debug it.

You need to use Import-Csv to get the data into PS. This will give you an array of PS Objects. From here, you can loop through each object and do what calculations you need.

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\test.csv

$data | Format-Table

foreach ($datum in $data) {
    if ($datum.Serial.StartsWith('C')) {
        $datum.result = $datum.Colour - $datum.Spotcol
    }

    else {
        if ($datum.Colour) { $datum.result = $datum.Colour }
        else { $datum.result = 0 }
    }
}

$data | Format-Table
```

Let's call each iteration of the `$data` array `$datum`. Your D column is titled `$datum.Colour`, E column is titled `$datum.Spotcol`, and A column is titled `$datum.Serial`. This is because each object of the array has the column titles as the attribute names instead of Excel's A2 D2 stuff.

At each iteration, if `$datum.Serial` [A2] starts with "C", we do `$datum.Colour` [D2] - `$datum.Spotcol` [E2] and assign it to `$datum.result` [F2]. Otherwise, we make `$datum.result` [F2] the value of `$datum.Colour` [D2].

Edit:

Made grammatical changes (`$data | FT` to `$data | Format-Table`)

Comment: Thank you for your help.. works perfect, ive have amended to save file with amended results but failing. sorry failry new to powershell. really appreciate the time people take to help other but